# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

Tags: java, android, mobile, import, sdk

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)

I've tried debugging, but I failed. Please help me. Thanks.

[image: Gradle excute error when run demo SDK]

Comment: paste your build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my code , and found that my application packages contains a **digit** in beginning of sentence. So i **removed that digit** and it worked for me.

**Example:** Wrong application package:

```
com.xyz.8xyzz
```

**Example:** Correct application package:

```
com.xyz.a8xyzz
```